# How-to know when Azure Analysis Services processing failed?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

When processing fails on SSAS on-prem I can send an error notification with SQL Agent.

On ADF/AAS the processing seems to be limited to async only and any error on AAS just floats away...

How can I send notifications out when the database processing fails?

In essence a simple ETL process runs sequentially. Either it completes successfully or something went wrong and needs human intervention. People should get notified about the error when it happens.

SQL Agent will email me when the Job/Process failed.

It really hurts when the customer calls you about an error you don't know about!

Comment: check if [Setup diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-logging) can help.

Comment: Analysis Services has [several different tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/monitor-an-analysis-services-instance?view=asallproducts-allversions) to help you monitor and tune the performance of your servers. And you said you use  SQL Agent to execute T-SQL on-prem?

Comment: It is not about monitoring or performance tuning. Nobody said T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

@hotpie,
you can have end to end notifications via below flow in ADF :

[image]

You can refer he below link for end to end details:

`https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/README.md#processazureas`